# invoke javax.el.MethodExpression from jsf component

Tags: java, jsf, jstl, method-invocation

I have a jsp tag which takes a javax.el.MethodExpression as attribute:

```
<%@ attribute name="action" required="true" type="javax.el.MethodExpression" rtexprvalue="true" %>
```

within the same tag I have:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{action}">
    link text
</h:commandLink>
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to click the link:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: #{action}: org.apache.jasper.el.JspMethodNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/tags/pager/pager.tag(17,1) '#{action}' Identity 'action' was null and was unable to invoke
```

is it possible for the commandLink to properly invoke the "action" method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create a JSP tag. Create a JSF component. Extend [`UIComponentELTag`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/webapp/UIComponentELTag.html). [Tutorials here](http://www.google.com/search?q=custom+component+%22extends+uicomponenteltag%22).

Or, if you're using Facelets, consider a [template](http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#template) using `ui:composition`. [Tutorials here](http://www.google.com/search?q=facelets+ui%3Acomposition).

Or, if you're already on JSF 2.0, you can get a step further with [composite components](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/composite/tld-summary.html). [Tutorial here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I did JSF, but I'm pretty sure a method expression is of the form: `#{bean.method}`. You can't just say `#{method}`.

Comment: yes, i'm passing the method to the tag i created:  <m:myTag action=${bean.method} /> and within the tag, i have to asign this method to the command link

Comment: Yea, that wont work. You can't pass method expressions around like that.